# problem in displaying JSON data in table view on iphone

Tags: ios4

i can parse data and see the output also but i am not able to  display them in table view

problem is 1st my tableviews code are executing then rest functions are working that's why i am getting 0 , how to avoid this ??

this is my code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {



    NSLog(@" value %d",[jsonArray count]);// always 0
    return  [jsonArray count];


}
```

in this method also i am getting 0 valuee

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
   *)indexPath {  NSDictionary *aTweet = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath
     row]];     NSLog(@ " divy is
     %@",aTweet);// nothing 

     }
```

other codes

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

 NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [json objectWithString:responseString error:nil];  





   NSDictionary *menu = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"name"];  
    //label.text=[dict objectForKey:@"firstName"];



     // parsing all the items in to the NSArray  

   NSArray *items = (NSArray *) [menu objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];  







    int ndx;
    //NSDictionary *stream;
    for (ndx = 0; ndx< items.count; ndx++) {

            stream = (NSDictionary *)[items objectAtIndex:ndx];


        NSLog(@"This is the title of a stream: %@", [stream valueForKey:@"type"]); 
        [jsonArray addObject:stream];


    }   

    NSLog(@" aray is %@",jsonArray);// show all data working
    NSLog(@" sterab is %@",[stream valueForKey:@"home"]);// this is also working
```

and this is my view did load()

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   





    jsonArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
        [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];       
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Json/Number.json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];            
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
}
```

Comment: problem is 1st my tableviews code  are executing then rest functions are working thats why i am getting 0 , how to avoid this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, the problem is that you data doesn't load immediately. And `UITableView`, when created, stores necessary data in some sort of cache. This allows to avoid often calls of data source's methods, like `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and others. So you should explicitly call `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method to refresh table.

To solve the problem, you should do something like this:

1. In `viewDidLoad` just show some spinner to indicate program activity.
2. In `connectionDidFinishLoading:` after all data was initialized, call `[yourTableView reloadData]`.

Comment: wow Awesome  Yes its working perfectly :-) thanks a lot i was struggling for 2 hours . whowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww